# How to I access the dictionary with multiple values inside list

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_isp_details = {'Jim': ['10.1387.32', 'Sim782']}

<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Gateway</th>
      </tr>
      {% for key, value in my_isp_details.items %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

How to pass the value 0 and 1 in table td. Is there any solution to pass the values

Comment: perhaps you want an inner for loop to iterate over the items in value?

Comment: yes how to put inner for loop

Comment: I need to put the first and second value in td

Comment: Shouldn't that be `my_isp_details.items()`? It's not clear what the actual problem here is otherwise. This is either a purely Python-based typo, or something specific to `jinja2`(?) templating.

Comment: @chepner Jim is a key AND ['10.1387.32', 'Sim782'] is value first td I need 10.1387.32 and second td i need Sim782

Comment: It is django to pass data from views to template

Comment: Yes; in Python at least, `for key, value in my_isp_deetails.items(): ` would set `key` to `"Jim"` and `value` to `['10.1387.32', 'Sim782']`, to `value[0]` and `value[1]` would be the right thing to do. Is that not what you get if you change `items` to `items()` here?

Comment: (You can use an inner loop if the number of `<td>` elements isn't known ahead of time, but here you seem to know that there are 2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to iterate over the items in your `value` perhaps like this:

```py
my_isp_details = {'Jim': ['10.1387.32', 'Sim782']}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Gateway</th>
    </tr>
    {% for key, value in my_isp_details.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            {% for inner_value in value %}
                <td>{{ inner_value }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```